# How to know the version and edition of citrix server

Tags: citrix

How to know which citrix metaframe presentation server's version and edition from where i am accessing my application.

I just want to know the version and edition.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If programmatically (`Python`) you want to do that then

First get the host record

```
record = xenapi.host.get_record(this)
```

Then retrieve the version from the record

```
version = '.'.join(record['software_version']['product_version'].split('.')[0:3])
```

Just print `record` and I believe you will get edition also there. And just do string operation to retrieve that.